# customising MPMovieplayer

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my new app,I have to show videos in MPMovieplayer.Client gave me the design as in screenshot
I want to know whether it is possible to customize like this(including the top like,skip buttons and the custom slider)

If it is possible,help me to learn more about that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily with `AV Foundation` specifically `AVPlayer` class, it is the framwork underneath MPMoviePlayer. It will give you the options to have an abstract video/audio player and you'll be able to create you own customize UI

Here's an example code to start with [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVSimplePlayerOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011060)

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayer will work, but I hear it can be more complicated than working with a more higer level solution like MPMoviePlayer. I've been working on making my own customized UI for a video stream using MPMoviePlayer.

Whenever you create your MPMoviePlayer object, just set control style to none with: `MPMovieControlStyleNone` this leaves your video player ready for you to make customize controls. I suggest using a `UIToolbar` and then setting UIBarButtonItems onto your toolbar. Once your toolbar has all your buttons, add the toolbar to the subview with the `addSubview` method. You can then add functionality to the buttons and slider with the [MPMediaPlayback Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) with methods like play and pause. By the way, the top like and skip buttons could just be UIButtons which are pretty customizable. Lastly, if you want the controls to disappear on a tap then look into [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html).

Of course you can style your buttons and position your toolbar as needed, but this should get you a basic start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom class I wrote that works in iOS6 and newer.
https://github.com/busterbooth/bbMoviePlayer

You can control and re-skin just about every aspect of the `MPMoviePlayer` as long as you do the following.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/video.file"]];
mp.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```